# Little logic should be test?

Tags: unit-testing

I have several classes that looks like: (some of them have dozens of cases)

```
function __construct($value) {
    switch ($value){
        case "1":
            $value = Values::One;
            break;
        case "2":
            $value = Values::Two;
            break;
        case "3":
            $value = Values::Three;
            break;
        case "4":
            $value = Values::Four;
            break;
        default:
            $value = null;
    }

    parent::__construct($value);
}
```

And I'm already test the parent class, should I have test this class too? should I test every possible path? i.e:

```
assertEquals(Values::One, new Clazz(1));
assertEquals(Values::Two, new Clazz(2));
assertEquals(Values::Three, new Clazz(3));
assertEquals(Values::Four, new Clazz(4));
```

or do only one assertion? `assertEquals(Values::One, new Clazz(1));` only

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How big does my project need to be for me to unit test it?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/159964/how-big-does-my-project-need-to-be-for-me-to-unit-test-it)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This kind of mapping logic is very easy to make mistakes in either when you initially write it or when an update is done.

You should have some test that verifies that the correct mapping is performed, including what happens if a value that can't be mapped is passed. If you have that as part of the tests for the parent class, then that is fine. Otherwise, you should create it for the current class.

If you have only a few values, like in the example you presented, then you might get away with it by just doing a review that all values are mapped correctly, but if you have a dozen or more values in a mapping, then it becomes very easy to overlook an error.

Comment: Thanks! I don't have such a validations in parent class so you recommend me test every case?

Comment: May I suggest a code change and move the mapping to its own class, so the child can do something like this: `parent::__construct(YourMapper::getValueFor($value));`. Then the mapping can be tested separately from instantiating a class.

Comment: @kwebble the mapping is all the purpose of this class, the parent just do few generic checks and put the value in datamember (that I can test)

Comment: You only provided the constructor so to me it looks like a normal child class. I did not understand it only has a constructor. Knowing that, it acts more like a sort of factory.

Answer (score 2):

If you do testdriven development one working example and a non-working axample is enought.

If you want an automatted test (with full coverage) writing the test is much more work than the actual implementation and you can never be shure if your test cover all aspects: i.e. if you later introduce a `Values::Fifteen` do you have a failing test that reminds you that `__construct(...)` is incomplete?

For this type of problem it may be easier to write an integration test if you have an inverse function like this

```
foreach(int id : allIds) assertThat(id).equals(name2id(id2Name(id))
```

this way you donot know if id and name has the right representation but you can be shure that for every id there is a working conversion.

I use this technique to verify that object (de)serialisation is complete:

```
String jsonString = aTestJsonWhereEveryPropertyHasAVaule;
MyComplexObject myObject = json2MyComplexObject(jsonSting);
String  result = myComplexObject2Json(myObject);
assertThat(jsonString ).equals(result);
```